# Use object methods inside UDF function pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to update a dataframe's column based on a complex computation (within a method inside a class).
From what I've learned so far, you can update columns in dataframes using user defined functions. Unfortunately, user defined functions must be static.
Is there any workaround?

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
'''
Louvain Community Detection Algoritm
'''
class LouvainCommunityDetection():

    def __init__(self, graph):

        self.graph = graph
        self.changeInModularity = True
        self.changeCommunityIdUDF = udf(LouvainCommunityDetection.changeCommunityId, IntegerType())


    @staticmethod
    def changeCommunityId(col):

        newCommunityId = 123
        # here I should compute the newCommunityId using complex operations
        # involving other methods in this class
        # like self.computeModularityGain
        # but since this is a static method... I can't use those
        return newCommunityId


    def louvain(self):

        oldModularity = 0 # since intially each node represents a community

        # retrieve graph vertices and edges dataframes
        verticesDf = self.graph.vertices
        edgesDf = self.graph.edges

        canOptimize = True

        while canOptimize:

            while self.changeInModularity:

                self.changeInModularity = False
                verticesDf = verticesDf.select('id', 'tweetCreated', 'userId', 'userName', 'parentId', self.changeCommunityIdUDF('communityId').alias('udfResult'))

                verticesDf.show()

                self.changeInModularity = False

            canOptimize = False
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution, [here](https://csyhuang.github.io/2019/09/24/pyspark-could-not-serialize-object/?fbclid=IwAR16z05mSbX3NORbRxRGuNgSHeoSlwSuwdrnmkFCP4-2txGA3Mn1ydPxoA0) there is an awesome and clear explanation.

The issue is that, when any of the object's members (for example `self.changeInModularity`) appears in the udf function, when applying it to the pyspark dataframe, the object self has to be serialized but it can't be.

A (surprisingly simple) way is to create a reference to that member but not the object:

```
changeInModularity = self.changeInModularity
```